# Sluggish Desktop Experience on Laptop with External 4K Monitor

Tags: nvidia, compiz, 15.04, performance, 4k-monitor

I just bought a ASUS PB287Q monitor and hooked it up (via HDMI) to my ASUS N550JK-DS521H. Everything works...but the performance of rendering on the external monitor is terrible. The experience on the laptop monitor is however perfect as before.

I've tested with and without monitor mirroring in the system settings. It has no effect on the sluggish experience. I'm suspecting that some kind of software buffering is involved in rendering to the second screen as there is slight delay in the external monitor rendering compared to the builtin screen rendering in mirrored mode.

Is there any use in trying another desktop such as GNOME?

Can I somehow tell Ubuntu to instead use the NVIDIA card (instead of the defaulted Intel) when rendering the external monitor?

Please help.

I'm sitting on 15.04 with its default (compiz) desktop. No software nor physical rotation is involved.

Command `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` outputs

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11cd
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11cd
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

**Update**: Ok, I've now installed `nvidia-346` and `nvidia-prime` and rebooted.

`glxinfo` says:

```
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 850M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 346.59
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.40 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
```

But still the same problem with sluggishness (only on external monitor). I'm suspecting compiz... What to try next?

*Update* I'm on NVIDIA now since `prime-select query` returns `nvidia`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Are you by any chance rotating the monitor? And are you connecting via dp or hdmi?

Comment: Oops. that command (I think) made my system hang...so I hade to reboot. Hang on...I'll see if I can pipe it. This time my system didn't hang. Strange. I added the output.

Comment: I added new driver to my answer. Maybe it improves performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Nvidia proprietary driver and switch to Nvidia adapter.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

You will be able to switch adapters in Nvidia Settings application.

You can also toggle adapters by running

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

and

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

You will have to log off and on to apply the selection.

For this new adapter you can try a newer driver. Run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

and reboot again.

Comment: Will that mean that the NVIDIA driver will render both screens?

Comment: @Nordlöw This is correct. But there may be some trouble with HDMI output. There were some questions related.

Comment: @Nordlöw You can also setup another `DISPLAY` for the second monitor, but I can't give a step-by-step solution.

Comment: So I can't simultaneously have one screen rendered through Intel and another through NVIDIA?

Comment: @Nordlöw I think you can. But it is not very straight forward. I've never done it myself. Any way it is better to install the driver.

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: @Nordlöw Probably it is compiz too slow on high resolutions.

Comment: Should I try GNOME instead?

Comment: @Nordlöw You can try Gnome, why not?

Comment: What will likely be better with NVIDIA 352? It's an unstable driver, right?

Comment: @Nordlöw It is the latest stable driver recommended by Nvidia according to their site nvidia.com. But it is not in Ubuntu repos yet.

Comment: Sigh..., I installed gnome-shell and gnome-session, rebooted and chose GNOME instead of Ubuntu. But now I can't login into GNOME. Instead I get a flickering every 3 seconds forever. If I reboot and switch back to Ubuntu it all works as previously. What's wrong with my GNOME configuration?

Comment: I tried XFCE aswell. Same flickering there aswell. What's wrong?